# Vector bundles are first cohomology sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

$\textbf{Disclaimer:}$ As suggested in the comments, I have reposted this question on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429387/vector-bundles-are-first-cohomology-sets)

Suppose $X$ is a variety, then we have the result that $\operatorname{H}^1(X, \mathcal{O}^*_X)=\operatorname{H}^1_{\acute{e}t}(X,\mathbb{G}_m)=\operatorname{Pic}(X).$ Which also holds in finer sites where coherent sheaves satisfy descent.

I know that a generalisation exists in the no-abelian setting of $\operatorname{GL}_n$, but I do not know exactly how to define $\operatorname{H}^1(-)$. Do you just define it as the set of torsors? Do you define it as a limit of $\check{\operatorname{C}}$ech cohomologies taken over every cover?

My best guess would be to follow the second one, because we want to continue to have something like $0\rightarrow\check{\operatorname{H}}^1(\mathcal{U}, G)\rightarrow \operatorname{H}^1(X, G)\rightarrow \check{\operatorname{H}}^0(\mathcal{U}, \underline{\operatorname{H}}^1(G))$ for a cover $\mathcal{U}$ and a non abelian sheaf $G$ (like in the abelian case using $\check{\operatorname{C}}$ech to sheaf spectral sequence). But this is only a guess, I am not sure.

Most of the answers I have found on the internet suggests I read Giraud's "Cohomologie non abelienne", but my lack of knowledge of French makes that very difficult.

Comment: This seems like an excellent question and I'd suggest asking it over on Math Overflow (with a note or link pointing back to this page, as is generally recommended for cross-posts, and an edit of this question to note the MO question); it feels research-level enough to be a good fit there.

Comment: Sure. I shall do that.

Comment: I think this is related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386688/h1x-gln-mathcalo-x-and-vector-bundles

Comment: The point is that you can define it either as Cech cohomology or as isomorphism classes of torsors, and they agree. The reason for this, roughly, is that Cech cohomology is describing the isomorphism classes of descent data over all possible covers of the final object, and such things are preicsely the isomorphism classes of torsors since torsors form a 'stack'. You can see Proposition 6.5.9 here: https://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/Qpoints.pdf

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks. This is really helpful